# How to understand this 'If', without a logic turn

Tags: american-english

A conversation starts with 'if' but without 'then' without 'else', without any logic turn.

Example:

> "If I tell you what we did...(details what they did)".
>
> "If I tell you how this ice cream taste, it is delicious"

How do I understand the 'if' logic?

Comment: "If" doesn't have to have to be followed by "then".  The logic turn can be implied:  *"If it's past 10, I really should go home"*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange!   Did you create the examples or did they come from somewhere?   In your examples, there is **no logic turn**, not even **implied**.   It is hard to think of a situation where this sounds correct.   The sentences you provided do not sound grammatically correct or natural.  Can you give a little more information about where they come from?

Comment: If somebody saying something start with "if", there always follows a "then" logic or "else" logic, although "then" or "else" is omitted maybe. I'm also stranged this saying "if I tell you, something...(over)". That example is from my memory, I may remember it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the main clause of a conditional sentence does not require a conjunction. It is grammatically correct to say:

> If it rains tomorrow, I will take my umbrella.
>
> I will take my umbrella if it rains tomorrow
>
> If it rains tomorrow, then I will take my umbrella.

The "else" clause does require some words such as "Otherwise", or "if not" to distinguish it.

> If it rains tomorrow, I will take my umbrella. Otherwise, I'll just wear my jacket.

Your example is not very clear, and doesn't involve logic. Instead when you say:

> If I tell you how this ice cream tastes, it is delicious.

I think you mean

> If I were to tell you how this ice cream tastes, I would tell you that it is delicious.

That uses a subjunctive and a conditional expression but is rather odd. Why make it a condition? This is a very long and confusing way of saying

> This ice cream is delicious.

Or perhaps, with a bit more style:

> Let me tell you how this ice cream tastes.  It's delicious!

Comment: I may have remembered it wrong. "If I were to tell you ..." is clear